# Get input in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, input

I know to get an input with a shell script you can do

```
echo "text"
read $VAR
```

or to get it at runtime

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$1" ]
then
  #do stuff
else
  echo "No input"
fi
```

But what if I want to get the entire string after I run it, including spaces?  I could use quotation marks, but is there any way around this, so I can do:
`./script.sh This is a sentence`

Comment: don't `echo text; read`, use `read -ptext var`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "$*"
else
    echo "No input"
fi
```

But first, think about what you're doing and just pass a single quoted parameter.

Comment: It sort-of works, provided you only have a single space between words and no other funny characters.  I'll repeat @Sorpigal's advice: think about what you're doing and just pass a single quoted parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
./script.sh "This is a sentence"
```

another way is

```
./script.sh This\ is\ a\ sentence
```

Comment: I said, "I could use quotation marks, but is there any way around this".